# Firebase when adding child, someother child gets removed

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a child to the child named: "users_want_notification". This seems to work, but when I try to add a second child to the child named: "users_want_notification" with a different name, then the first child will be removed. How can I change this, so the first child wont be removed?

My code:

```
Database.database().reference()
  .child("Notification").child("users").child(username)
  .setValue(["username": username, "url": Foto_url])
Database.database().reference()
  .child("Notification").child("users").child(username)
  .child("users_want_notification").child(Pro_user)
  .setValue(["Pro_user": Pro_user, "toDeviceID": AppDelegate.DEVICEID])
```

Firebase:

[image: Firebase]

Comment: I'm not sure why you tagged with `google-cloud-firestore`, as both your code and screenshot show the `firebase-realtime-database`. I modified the tag, but please take care to use the correct tags yourself going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `setValue` on a child node, all existing data under that node is replaced by the value(s) you pass to `setValue`. If we look at your first call:

```
Database.database().reference()
  .child("Notification").child("users").child(username)
  .setValue(["username": username, "url": Foto_url])
```

This replaces all existing data under `/Notification/users/$username`, including all data under its `users_want_notification` child node. Since you then add a new child node under `users_want_notification`, it looks like that call replaces the existing child, but it's actually the first `setValue` that deletes all data. You can test this by momentarily commenting out the second call, and you'll see that the entire `users_want_notification` disappears.

You have two main options:

1. Use separate `setValue` calls for the individual `username` and `url` properties:

   ```
   let userRef = Database.database().reference()
     .child("Notification").child("users").child(username)
   userRef.child("username").setValue(username)
   userRef.child("url").setValue(Foto_url])
   userRef.child("users_want_notification").child(Pro_user)
     .setValue(["Pro_user": Pro_user, "toDeviceID": AppDelegate.DEVICEID])
   ```

   Since all `setValue` calls now happen at levels lower than `/Notification/users/$username`, that entire node is never replaced.
2. Use a single `updateChildNodes` call for all data, performing a [multi-location update](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)).